# How to change the color of title/views

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube-api

Is there a way to change the color of the title and views from blue and black to white in this youtube-api feed? The working site can be found [here](http://netx.clanteam.com/vs/video.html).

```
    link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="files/style6.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/jquery-1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#main_block").append("<div id = 'data'><ul>.</ul></div>");
        var dataContainer = $("#data ul");
        $.ajax({
            url:'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/googledevelopers/uploads?max-results=50&time=today&alt=jsonc&v=2&callback=?',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            timeout: 5000,
            success: function(data){

                     $.each(data.data.items, 
                               function(i, val) {

                                 if (typeof(val.player) !== 'undefined' && typeof(val.title) !== 'undefined') {

                                    dataContainer.append('<div class="d e"><a href='+val.player["default"]+' target="_blank" title="'+val.title+'">'+val.title+'</a><br /><img src="'+val.thumbnail.sqDefault+'" width="120" height="90" alt="'+val.title+'"/><br />Views '+val.viewCount+'</div>');
                                 }
                         });
                    }
                });
            });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i have not misunderstood your question , Put this in your stylesheet file

```
#data div.d a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#data div.d {
    color: white;
}
```